# Excel =(Formula to add +1 every day)

Tags: excel, libreoffice

i am trying to make excel cell count the number of dates passed since the last time i have edited that cell.

eg: A1 = Info1 A2 = 10

Cell A1 Edited 10 Days ago.

how can i create this in excel and LibreOffice please

i tried some formulas but don't have the exact results and complicated to understand.

Comment: What formulas have you tried? Something like `TODAY() - <date>` where `<date>` is the date you modified that cell should do it

Comment: There is no formula in Excel which can do that. You have to put the editing date in another cell, only then you can make a formula.